# How to create Buy Now buttons for different merchants in paypal

Tags: paypal

I have a Digital Service Providing website. This service allows **user's customers** to take appointments for the services **user** is providing. Now the customers must be able to Pay for the service before confirming the appointment.

My requirement is each user of my website have different services and different price for it.
They have already configured these services on my web application. I have all details in the database.Now how can i integrate Pay Now buttons for this scenario? I do not want the user to configure the service price again on Paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can handle that.  Do you have a shopping cart system setup on the site so people can browse and add service items and checkout all at once, or how exactly is that setup?

If you're tracking items and order price within a shopping cart you can use [Payments Standard Cart Upload Method](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload) to easily gather order details and send the user over to PayPal for payment.

You could also use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) if you prefer web services.  If you want to offer credit cards directly (without any PayPal redirect) you could include [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wpp) as well.

If you want to stick with standard buttons, but you want to automate the process, you can use the [Button Manager API](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_wpsbuttonmgrapinvp.pdf).

Comment: I want to initiate the payments on behalf of my clients.e.g lets say One of my clients provides different cars on rent. So for different cars the fare will be different.Now when the customer is booking a particular car he should first pay the rent and then his booking will get confirmed.How can I achieve this as every time the merchant will be different providing different services.

Comment: My answer wouldn't be any different than what I said already.  What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have tried implementing the Button Manager API(Soap).I am able to implement it if i knew the api username,api password and api signature of the merchant. So i will have to capture the API credentials of the users. Is this approach correct? Also i have found "Granting Third-Party Permission for APIs" in the pdf but do not know how to implement it. May be this will help me to create buttons without capturing the API credentials. Please guide me on this. Thank you.